# Is it possible to make a Cloud page return a Status Code 400?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

In the context of using a Cloud page as an endpoint for an API call,

I was wondering if it was possible to make a Cloud page return content with a different Status Code, such as 400 for example.

In PHP pretty simple: `<?php header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"); ?>`

But on a Cloud page it doesn't seem possible...

I already tried using the following code in server-side JavaScript, but no luck, it returns 200:

```
HTTPHeader.SetValue('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request','');
HTTPHeader.SetValue('Status Code', 400);
```

`RaiseError` doesn't seem to work either, at least not the one from the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityRaiseError.htm).

Comment: Seems like the answer is No from all I have researched due to the way they layer SSJS onto the server. I think this would be a great thing though to push onto IdeaExchange or in general push to Salesforce. Having this capability would open many doors of possibility to the SFMC Developer.